# dotdotdot.js only works after a window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to append an ellipsis to several multiline paragraphs on my website when they exceed a certain height. To this end I am using [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/), the jquery plugin.

The weird thing is that it doesn't work when i refresh the page. It only works after I resize the window (and then it works perfectly). I've already tried putting all the scripts at the end of my html so dotdotdot gets loaded last, but it still doesn't work properly. Does anyone know why this would happen?

I'm using these settings for dotdotdot:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p.article-content").dotdotdot(
    {
        /* The HTML to add as ellipsis. */
        ellipsis : '...',

        /* How to cut off the text/html: 'word'/'letter'/'children' */
        wrap : 'word',

        /* jQuery-selector for the element to keep and put after the ellipsis. */
        after : null,

        /* Whether to update the ellipsis: true/'window' */
        watch : true,

        /* Optionally set a max-height, if null, the height will be measured. */
        height : null,

        /* Deviation for the height-option. */
        tolerance : 0,

        /* Callback function that is fired after the ellipsis is added,
        receives two parameters: isTruncated(boolean), orgContent(string). */
        callback : function( isTruncated, orgContent ) {},

        lastCharacter : {
            /* Remove these characters from the end of the truncated text. */
            remove : [ ' ', ',', ';', '.', '!', '?' ],

            /* Don't add an ellipsis if this array contains
            the last character of the truncated text. */
            noEllipsis : []
        }
    });
});
```

The relevant HTML is (it's ugly, I know, I'm still experimenting with it):

```
<article class="article">
  <div class="article-image"></div>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p class="date">December 19, 2012</p>
  <p class="article-content">Lorem ipsum etc. (the actual content is larger)</p>
</article>
```

And the CSS:

```
article {
  font-size: 99%;
  width: 28%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 8%;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  text-align: justify;
}

article h2 {
  font-size: 125%;
  line-height: 0.5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}

.date {
  margin-top: 0.3em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-family: 'PT Sans';
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.article-image {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/g/400/300/city/7);
  width: 100%;
  height: 13em;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

p.article-content {
  font-family   : 'PT Sans';
  color         : rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
  margin-bottom : 0;
  height        : 7em;
  overflow      : hidden;
}
```

Comment: Try using the window load event instead so that it waits until after images are all loaded.

Comment: can you share your css?

Comment: @KevinB, you mean $(window).ready instead of $(document).ready? I've tried that, doesn't make a difference unfortunately..

Comment: @Samuel No, i mean window load. `$(window).load(function(){...})`

Comment: @DanielA.White, of course! I've added it to the question.

Comment: @KevinB Ah, that works. There is a flash of unstyled content though. Could this be because window load is slower somehow than document ready?

Comment: @Samuel Yes, window load is slow than document ready, it waits a little longer to let all the assets download.

Comment: @KevinB, a final question: do you know why dotdotdot doesn't work for me with document ready, and does with window load? Could it be that the images I'm using are too large and interfering with dotdotdot's operation? And is there a way to fix this without the FOUC?

Comment: It doesn't work on document ready because it can't properly calculate the width/height of the paragraph tags before the assets are done loading. There's always going to be a FOUC when using the dotdotdot plugin because it has to first render it completely to calculate where it should cut off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or, simply wrap the entire function under a `.resize()` function. Not the most elegant solution but it will work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function()
    {
        $("p.article-content").dotdotdot(
        {
            // All your code goes here
        });
    }).resize();

    // The second .resize() will fire when the document is ready (i.e. onload),
    // therefore executing .dotdotdot() upon loading
});
```

[Edit]:
Per Kevin's suggestion, since `.dotdotdot()` already listens to the resize event, you don't even need to wrap the function. Simply trigger the event when the document is ready, using `$(window).resize()`.

Comment: Or just trigger resize since dotdotdot already listens to the resize event.

Comment: @KevinB in this case yes, because `watch : true`. Kind of awkward that dotdotdot is not providing more examples/snippets on their website http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/

Answer (score 3):

had a similar problem. just had to put the dotdotdot initialization in a window load eventhandler instead of the dom ready.

Comment: I was having a similar problem with a completely different JS library, and this seems to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

At first it seemed so easy with dotdotdot. But I got this problem also with responsive page which contained a lot of content. After document is ready the containers on the page are still beeing resized because content is filling in.
With help of your comments my solution is now:

```
$(document).ready(ellipsizeText);        // Plugin must have been working flawles inhere as described in documentation.
window.setTimeout(ellipsizeText, 400);   // Just for any case.
window.setTimeout(ellipsizeText, 800);   // Maybe user didn't saw it flickering.
$(window).load(ellipsizeText);           // Oh hell! the images are loading so not all containers are yet on their places. We wait on them..
function ellipsizeText()
{
    $(".selectorForEllipsis").dotdotdot({
        watch: true
    });
}
```

I think that the proper solution would be to append listener to every container with text when that changes position or size to update dotdotdot, not just to window resize. Maybe with [Ben Alman yquery resize plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/)

Or does exists plugin that handles this content loading problems better?

Comment: That was great. Bravo

Answer (score 0):

Changed from
  watch: "window" 
to
  watch: true

and it started working for me!